# id2word_token2Id usage confusion in Gensim

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, gensim

In order to make it clear, I would like to get your feedback whether the following code/gensim-usage is right or not?

Thank you in advance for your valuable time.

```
import gensim    

train = ["John likes to watch movies Mary likes movies too" ,
         "John also likes to watch football games" ]

test = ["Football is my dream"]

train_texts = [[word for word in document.lower().split()] for document in train]
test_texts = [[word for word in document.lower().split()] for document in test]

dictionary =gensim.corpora.Dictionary(train_texts)

train_corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in train_texts]
test_corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in test_texts]

ldaModel = gensim.models.LdaModel(corpus=train_corpus , 
             id2word=dictionary , num_topics=2)
bound_perplex = ldaModel.bound(test_corpus)
```

Comment: I investigated with other people. It is as it is supposed to be. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The code usage is absolutely right, but it would be better to use corpus streaming for larger documents.

You can get more info about data streaming here -

1. https://rare-technologies.com/data-streaming-in-python-generators-iterators-iterables/
2. https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tut1.html#corpus-streaming-one-document-at-a-time